# How to sort query result with hit count

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I've indexed some info into ElasticSearch like

```
{"info":"002345 Groot 7AP"}
```

and supported a query template

```
GET _search?size=5
`{"query": {
   "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "info": "%s"
   }
 }
}`
```

so I can search info by any terms.

the default order is `"_score":"desc"`
and now I want to return query results sorting by hit count, so the frequently used infos would show up.

I read some `aggregation` api on elastic.co, but don't know how to write the query body.

Thanks.

Comment: Question: What do you mean by `sort by hit count`?
Please post the result body that you are getting and an example of the result body that you do want after executing this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this if this works:

`{
    "aggs": {
        "top_tags": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "type",
                "size": 3
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_sales_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "_score": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
    }
}`
```